# Flutter textfield onChanged don't work when textfield bring value from controller

Tags: flutter, dart, textfield

I'm working on flutter project and came across a problem. the textfield supposed to take a value from controller which work perfectly but onChanged function wont work. However it is not working.i must retype value to show results .

how can i get result from onchanged when my textfield brings the value ?

code:
// search function that call api

```
class _SearchPageTState extends State<SearchPageT> {
  GlobalState _store = GlobalState.instance;
  List<dynamic> searchResults = [];
  searchT(value) async {
    SearchServicet.searchApiT(value).then((responseBody) {
      List<dynamic> data = jsonDecode(responseBody);
      setState(() {
        data.forEach((value) {
          searchResults.add(value);
        });
      });
    });
  }
  @override
```

///////
//code textfield search onchanged

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: [
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
              child: TextField(
                autofocus: true,
                controller: TextEditingController()
                  ..text = '${_store.get('num')}',
                onChanged: (value) {
                  searchResults.clear();
                  searchCodeighniterT(value);
                },
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0),
                  labelText: 'number',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    onPressed: null,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10.0,
            ),
            ListView.builder(
              physics: ScrollPhysics(),
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: searchResults.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return buildResultCard(context, searchResults[index]);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

//here where shows the result

```
Widget buildResultCard(BuildContext context, data) {
  return Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        new Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("assets/bgwlgo.png"), fit: BoxFit.cover),
          ),
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "DATE:",
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    data['DATETIME'].toString(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    "TRAITEMENT:",
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    data['TRAITEMENT_DETAIL'].toString()
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              new Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(9.0),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        Divider(
          color: Colors.black,
        )
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried reproducing your issue in isolation? Outside the context of your app. Testing just the onChanged method of the TextField, and if it works, add more of the complexity you have present in your application, until it breaks and you can identify he issue?

Comment: yes, I tried the onchenged method which works perfectly when I type the value manually, but when I call the value from the controller no result is displayed, so I have to re-type the value manually for it to work

Comment: Let me see if I have understood your issue correctly. You want to have the `onChanged` method to be called when your change the `TextField` via the controller? Have you tried using a listener to do that same trigger?

Comment: I'll explain, when I open this page the controller automatically sends the value to the textfield, I would like the onChanged method to be triggered to detect the value of the textfield. so yes, this is what i want, can you help me do this method thank you so much

Comment: Are you hard coding the text in the controller? If not, are you passing it from another class or from the navigation, and if that is the case, why don't you just check if the variable has data on your `initState` and run the same method that you would on the ònChange`?

Comment: I'm using a class that makes me pass the value of a textfeild from a page to the textfield of that page in question, can you show me please how to do it on my code

Comment: I've posted an answer below. Check if that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed and understood in the comments, here are a couple of possible solutions for the issue.

If you are using a stateful Widget and need a controller for your TextFormField, you can use it to set the text on the TextFormField. Otherwise, you can just use the initialValue property:

```
class TextFieldIssue64061076 extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children:[
        Text('Page 1'),
        TextFormField(
          controller: _textEditingController,
        ),
        FlatButton(
          child: Text('Submit'),
          onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) {
              return SecondPage64061076(text: _textEditingController.text);
            }
          )),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage64061076 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;

  SecondPage64061076({
    this.text
  });

  @override
  _SecondPage64061076State createState() => _SecondPage64061076State();
}

class _SecondPage64061076State extends State<SecondPage64061076> {
  final TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    //  You can either use a text controller to set the text on the text field
    // or the initialValue below
    if(widget.text != null && widget.text != ''){
      _textEditingController.text = widget.text;
      methodToCallOnChanged(widget.text);
    }else{
      _textEditingController.text = '';
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Text('Page 2'),
          TextFormField(
            controller: _textEditingController,
            onChanged: (value) => methodToCallOnChanged(value),
            // As mentioned you could just use the initial value, it you don't need
            // a Stateful Widget
            // initialValue: widget.text ?? '',
          ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }

  void methodToCallOnChanged(data){
    print('I was called onChange or when the view opened and there was data');
  }
}
```

Comment: this will allow me to retrieve the value on the textfeild of the second page, (thing that already works) controller: TextEditingController ()
                   ..text = '$ {_ store.get (' num ')}',
But how to call the function mentioner on the onchanged method as soon as the textfield retrieves the value

Comment: once the value retrieved in the textfield an action is triggered to call another function as you can see on my code
onChanged: (value) {
                   searchResults.clear ();
                   searchCodeighniterT (value);
                 },

Comment: Thank you very much in advance for everything you have done to help me,hoping to find a solution that could help others in the future

Comment: You are right. I will add the missing code regarding the onChange, and triggering the same method when coming from another view.

Comment: Mr João Soares finally it works, I do not know how to thank you, god protect you, god send you to help me after a long week of hard work, thank you once again Mr.

Comment: I'm glad you managed to make it work! Please consider up voting for relevance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool isRecording = false;
    bool isShowSendButton = false;
    /// make sure textcontroller and any variabloes or booleans are not defined 
    ///in the  build method
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be using the constructor of the TextEditingController and assign it to the controller.
The controller of the TextField only takes the variable assigned to the `TextEditingController`. Check the following code.

controller:theNameOfYourController

```dart
Expanded(
  flex: 8,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 10),
    child: TextFormField(
      onChanged: (value){
        messageFieldController.text=value;
      },
      //controller: messageFieldController,
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: 2,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefixIcon: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          icon: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.blue),
        ),
        suffixIcon: processing == true
            ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
            : IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  try {
                    /*for (int i = 0;
                        i < widget.selectedMembers.length;
                        i++) {
                      sendMessage(
                          widget.selectedMembers[i].number);
                    }*/
                    for (int i = 0;
                        i < widget.selectedGroups.length;
                        i++) {
                      if (widget.selectedGroups.isNotEmpty) {
                        sendMessageToGroup(
                            widget.selectedGroups[i].id,
                            widget.selectedGroups[i].groupName);
                      }
                    }
                  } catch (err) {
                    Fluttertoast.showToast(
                        msg: 'Unable to send Message');
                    setState(() {
                      processing = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
                icon:
                    const Icon(Icons.send, color: Colors.blue),
              ),
        border: const OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(50),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: All iI'm saying is  you assigned a constructor instead of a textEditing variable to the textfield controller